# Migrate legacy network to custom VPC - Google Colud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

I need to convert my single-region Google cloud legacy network to a VPC network.
I have tried both single-region conversion tool and the [GKE network conversion script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-network-conversion)

In both I receive the following error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.networks.update) The first 2 IPs in this network's range 10.240.0.0/16 must be in used.`

The fist two IPs mentioned in the error message are network IP `10.240.0.0` and the default gateway `10.240.0.1`. The problem is that these two IP addresses are assigned to the legacy network by default and can not be changed.

On the [guides](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-legacy#prepare-convert-network) it only asks to ensure that the **last** two IPs of the network `10.240.0.254` and `10.240.0.255` are free. Which are also free in my case, and the first two IP addresses are not in the requirements.

I couldn't find this error ins the troubleshooting section of the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-legacy#troubleshooting).

Has anyone faced this issue before and managed to solve?

EDIT-1: In use IP addresses and their associated resources in the default legacy network are as follow:

```
10.240.0.1      default gateway
10.240.0.3      compute#instance
10.240.0.4      compute#instance
10.240.0.7      compute#instance
10.240.0.18     compute#instance
10.240.0.22     compute#instance
10.240.0.23     compute#instance
10.240.0.28     compute#instance
10.240.0.31     compute#instance
10.240.0.34     compute#instance
10.240.0.37     compute#instance
10.240.0.39     compute#instance
10.240.0.43     compute#instance
10.240.0.44     compute#instance
10.240.0.56     compute#instance
10.240.0.58     compute#instance
10.240.0.60     compute#instance
10.240.0.68     compute#instance
10.240.0.75     compute#instance
10.240.0.81     compute#instance
10.240.0.84     compute#instance
10.240.0.101    compute#instance
10.240.0.105    compute#instance
10.240.0.106    compute#instance
10.240.0.109    compute#instance
10.240.0.111    compute#instance
10.240.0.117    compute#instance
10.240.0.123    compute#instance
10.240.0.124    compute#instance
10.240.0.133    compute#instance
10.240.0.137    compute#instance
10.240.0.175    compute#instance
10.240.92.185   compute#instance
10.240.117.221  compute#instance
```

EDIT-2: used commands and their outputs

using `gkeconvert` command from [GKE network conversion script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-network-conversion)

```
gkeconvert                                \
 --project=<project-name>                 \
 --network=<legacy-network-name>          \
 --control-plane-version=1.23.14-gke.1800 \
 --node-version="-"                       \
 --validate-only=false


INFO[0000] Fetching network <legacy-network-name> for project "<project-name>"
INFO[0001] Initialize objects for conversion.
INFO[0002] Initialize NodePool objects for Cluster projects/<project-name>/locations/<gcloud-zone>/clusters/<gke-cluster-name>
INFO[0005] Validate resources for conversion.
INFO[0005] Upgrade for Cluster projects/<project-name>/locations/<gcloud-zone>/clusters/<gke-cluster-name> is valid
INFO[0005] Validate NodePool upgrade(s) for Cluster projects/<project-name>/locations/<gcloud-zone>/clusters/<gke-cluster-name>
INFO[0005] Upgrade for NodePool projects/<project-name>/locations/<gcloud-zone>/clusters/<gke-cluster-name>/nodePools/<pool-1-name> is valid
INFO[0005] Upgrade for NodePool projects/<project-name>/locations/<gcloud-zone>/clusters/<gke-cluster-name>/nodePools/<pool-2-name> is valid
INFO[0005] Upgrade for NodePool projects/<project-name>/locations/<gcloud-zone>/clusters/<gke-cluster-name>/nodePools/<pool-3-name> is valid
INFO[0005] Upgrade for NodePool projects/<project-name>/locations/<gcloud-zone>/clusters/<gke-cluster-name>/nodePools/<pool-4-name> is valid
INFO[0005] Upgrade for NodePool projects/<project-name>/locations/<gcloud-zone>/clusters/<gke-cluster-name>/nodePools/<pool-5-name> is valid
INFO[0005] Initiate resource conversion.
INFO[0005] Switching legacy network projects/<project-name>/global/networks/<legacy-network-name> to custom mode VPC network
Error: error waiting on Operation projects/<project-name>/global/operations/operation-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx: The first 2 IPs in this network's range 10.240.0.0/16 must be in used.
```

using [single-region conversion](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/networks/update) tool

```
gcloud beta compute networks update <legacy-network-name>  --switch-to-custom-subnet-mode
Network [<legacy-network-name>] will be switched to custom mode. This operation cannot be undone.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

X Migrating Network from Legacy to Custom Mode
  . Validating Network
  . Creating Subnetwork
  . Updating Instances
  . Updating Instance Groups
  . Updating Forwarding Rules
  . Converting Network to Subnet Mode
Failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.networks.update) The first 2 IPs in this network's range 10.240.0.0/16 must be in used.
```

Comment: Can you share the in use IP addresses and the associated resources in the legacy network, if none, can you attach a resource on the legacy network using the ip range 10.240.0.0/16 and perform again the migration.

One workaround that I can think of is by doing the [Manual migrate to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-legacy#manual-migration)

Comment: I added the in used IP addresses and the resources.
Manual aporach requires recreating every resources with the same configurations which in result will increase the maintanance window time and can result in disruptions to services while single-region conversion tool does not disrupt network traffic and resources continue to operate normally.
But eventually if couldn't sort this out I'll go in that direction.

Comment: I see, I know you already shared the documentation you followed for this concern, but can you share the commands that you run for this migration?

Comment: I added the edit2 with the two commands and their outputs. It was going to be great if there was a flag like `--internal-ipv6-range` available for ipv4

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for editing the question with detailed information about the commands you run, its result and Ips with attached resources for this conversion. Since everything in the documentation mentioned was followed correctly, I believe this concern is already an issue.

I suggest to create an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) mention these details so they would know how to resolve the issue. Upon checking this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) Under “Issue Tracker” it is mentioned that Google reviews every new issue reports and even one of their staff will ask for clarification for follow ups then it will forward to the appropriate team.

For a workaround on this concern which I'm sure you already know is by doing it manually just like what I shared in our comment section. [Manually Migrate to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-legacy#manual-migration).

However, if there’s one thing that I observed. We don't have a resource in IP address 10.240.0.2, I believe the first two usable IP addresses will be 10.240.0.1 and 10.240.0.2. I am aware that it should be 10.240.0.0 but since we cannot use this IP address and we are having an error message, just for troubleshooting purposes we can try to add resource on 10.240.0.2 then try to run the commands again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I opened the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268248358). P.S : Adding the new VM with IP `10.240.0.2` did not change anything.